# Parse.com: getting UserCannotBeAlteredWithoutSessionError

Tags: javascript, angularjs, parse-platform

I have an Angular service that takes in a roleId and userId and assigns the user to that role and make a pointer in User to that role.

```
app.service('CRUD', function () {
    this.addUserToRole = function (roleId, userId) {
        // first we have to find the role we're adding to
        var query = new Parse.Query(Parse.Role);
        return query.get(roleId, {
            success: function (role) {
                // then add the user to it
                var Database = Parse.Object.extend("User");
                var query = new Parse.Query(Database);
                console.log(role);
                return query.get(userId, {
                    success: function (user) {
                        console.log(user);
                        role.getUsers().add(user);
                        role.save();

                        // now we need to tell the user that he has this role
                        console.log(user);
                        user.attributes.role.add(role);
                        user.save();
                        return user;
                    },
                    error: function (err) {
                        return err;
                    }
                });
            },
            error: function (err) {
                console.log(err);
            }
        });
    }
});
```

I'm getting `{"code":206,"error":"Parse::UserCannotBeAlteredWithoutSessionError"}` on `user.save();`

After some research, I arrived at [this](https://parse.com/questions/users-editing-other-users-in-javascript-sdk) website. He uses this code snippet as a JS SDK example:

```
Parse.Cloud.run('modifyUser', { username: 'userA' }, {
  success: function(status) {
    // the user was updated successfully
  },
  error: function(error) {
    // error
  }
});
```

and mentions something about a `useMasterKey()` function.

I'm still unsure how to fix this error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add

```
Parse.Cloud.useMasterKey();
```

at the beginning of your function.

Answer (score 0):

Set it up as a background job. That is the code snip you found I think and a simpler far more secure means of fondling users and roles

https://parse.com/docs/cloud_code_guide#jobs